# C# ClosedXML library insert extra column without affecting existing formulas

Tags: c#, closedxml

I am working on a existing project where every column is defined hard-coded, from A till DZ and lots of columns/rows has a formula defined (also set hard-code in code)

Now I need to add an extra column on the 3th index, please tell me that it can be inserted without find/replace all existing defined formulas in this 2000 lines class.

Comment: now I *really* want to see that 2000 lines class. please include it in the question

Comment: You must be kidding me now right? Its for an Excel sheet with more than 100 columns. And in code everything is hardcoded based on the alphabetical letters A - DZ.

I can manually add a new column on index D, but the issue is all formula's, I'm not in the mood for replacing everything by hand..

Formula's like this f.e: SUMIF($DH$9:$DH${1},$C{0},DL$9:DL${1}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes but there is nothing to reproduce because there is no bug right? Just a question. Thanks for posting anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for `InsertColumnsAfter` and `InsertColumnsBefore` functions being available on column and range.

Here's a litte example with a newly created Excel file clarifying the usage:

```
private void ExcelExample()
{
    string xlsx = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".xlsx";
    XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
    IXLWorksheet ws = wb.AddWorksheet("Table1");
    ws.Cell(1, 1).SetValue("Col1");
    ws.Cell(1, 2).SetValue("Col2");
    ws.Cell(1, 3).SetValue("Col3");
    ws.Cell(2, 1).SetFormulaA1("=A1");
    ws.Cell(2, 2).SetFormulaA1("=B1");
    ws.Cell(2, 3).SetFormulaA1("=C1");
    ws.Column(1).InsertColumnsAfter(1);
    ws.Cell(1, 2).SetValue("Col1.5");
    ws.Range("D:D").InsertColumnsBefore(1);
    ws.Cell(1, 4).SetValue("Col2.5");
    wb.SaveAs(xlsx);
    Process.Start(xlsx);
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try today thanks

Comment: Easy as that, very great!